# Regular Expression for two integers, three decimals (XX.XXX)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that will allow the user to enter up to two integers, and three decimal places. Thanks.

Comment: `/\d{2}\.\d{3}/` That is what I call a "baby regex"

Comment: Javascript, or Objective-c? Make up your mind...

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
[0-9]{0,2}\.[0-9]{0,3}
```

Answer (score 0):

This following regex accepts 1 or 2 digits and can optionally be followed by a dot and 1 to 3 more digits. Patterns like "5." will be rejected, but "5.0" will be accepted.

```
/^\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,3}){0,1}$/
```